# Numerical difference between columns VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with 15000 rows of data. I have numerical values in Columns D & E . I have to calculate the difference between  D & E and store it in F using VBA. I am new to VBA Help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have to do it using VBA? A formula is much easier..

Comment: This value will be used later in the code so formula is difficult

Comment: `Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 100
    Cells(i, 6).Value = Cells(i, 5).Value - Cells(i, 4).Value
Next i`

Comment: Brother i have 15000 rows of data, So is there a faster way other than loops

Comment: `Range("F1:F15000").Formula = "=D1-E1"`?

Comment: @BigBen's soluiton is pretty fast than mine.     `Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    StartTime = Timer
    For i = 1 To 15000
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value - Cells(i, 1).Value
        DoEvents
    Next i
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
    MsgBox "Finito (" & SecondsElapsed & " seconds)"
    
    
    StartTime = Timer
    Range("D1:D15000").Formula = "=B1-A1"
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
    MsgBox "Finito (" & SecondsElapsed & " seconds)"`

Comment: You could dump the data in an array. Calculate the difference and dump it back. Using Arrays instead of ranges is usually faster

Answer (score 0):

Is it absolutely necessary that you use VBA for this ? If I understand the question correctly this would be much easier to do with excel formulas rather than using an array and having to loop through.

In cell `F1` you need to type the following formula:
`= D1-E1`

Be sure to include the equals sign. Then press enter. Double click the bottom right corner of cell in `F1` and it should auto fill all the way down.

Hope this helps. This is my first post so hopefully I haven't done anything wrong !

Comment: You have done nothing wrong :). Your answer is completely valid but have a look at BigBen's comment. Combination of formulas and code can be a very powerful tool

Comment: Yeah that's a cracking answer didnt realise you could put formulas in the code that is great ! Nice one liner too. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

For data between rows 2 and 15000, run:

```
Sub SplitTheDifference()
    Range("F2:F15000").Formula = "=D2-E2"
End Sub
```

The formulas adjust as we move down the columns

If we need values rather than formulas in column **F**, use:

```
Sub SplitTheDifference()
    With Range("F2:F15000")
        .Formula = "=D2-E2"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```